# Why am I getting these errors in the spring tool suite. I think it is because I am missing some libraries but I am not sure

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have the following imports and on each of them I get an error.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
```

The error is "The import org.apache.log4j cannot be resolved." Each one specific to the import that is listed. What can this be?

Comment: Have you added the jars to your project's build path?

Comment: It means it cannot find the class files you specify on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the required libraries (log4j and spring-web) are available on the build-path of your project.

Comment: How do I do this? I assumed the spring tool suite would include these files.

Comment: No, you have to add them yourself.  Right click on the project, properties > Java Build path and add external JARs and locate the jar files that contain the mentioned libraries.

Answer (score 0):

[image]make sure check, right click project -> properties-> java build path-> libraries has those jars